# Cannot install NVIDIA nForece 630a / GeForce 7025 drivers for ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, 19.10

I have an ASUS board (m4n68t-m le v2) with on board Nvidia graphics chipset model#: nForce 630a/ GeForce 7025. I have Windows 10 installed and I have now installed Ubuntu 19.10 on the same HDD having a dual boot scenario. The problem is i am not able to find and install the correct nvidia driver version on ubuntu.

I have to say I am fairly new to Linux, hence from various sources/forums, here is what I have done so far:

```
blacklisted default open source nouveau driver
ran update-initramfs -u after that
downloaded the compatible .run package from nvidia site and tried installing. every time there is a kernel error. tried all options - with/without DKMS etc.
tried installing using package manager using: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx. Not able to connect to Nvidia driver error. Had to move back to nouveau.

Additional problems: a) ubuntu-drivers devices: returns nothing. b) from software & updates GUI - nothing appears in additional drivers tab (no recomended drivers etc.) c) lspci | grep VGA command shows the correct adapter information: 00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025/ nForce630a] (rev a2)

Many forums say to disable Secure Boot or UEFI mode, but both options are missing from my BIOS. Its currently running in Legacy (MBR) mode.
Formatted the partitions and re-installed ubuntu but with no luck. ran: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y etc.. no use!
```

Kernel (uname -r) :5.3.0-24-generic Ubuntu Version: 19.10

Have been trying to fix this for over a week now. With no resolution. So any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: basically you need to download drivers from https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/114714 and follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I installed nvidia drivers for such GPU by executing `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.135.run`